# Query to polybase external table giving error "Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, polybase

we have successfully created all pre-requisite of creating external tables using SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition CU22 Polybase.

The issue we have is the non-sysadmin login can't query those external tables .It shows below error.

> Msg 7416, Level 16, State 2, Line 29
> Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.

The sysadmin login can query external tables without any issue.
Is there anybody saw this issue and can help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is directly related to your issue but the [known limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-versioned-feature-summary?view=sql-server-ver15#known-limitations) on PolyBase state that:

> In order to use PolyBase, you must have sysadmin or CONTROL SERVER
> level permissions on the database

As such you might try to:

```
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [LoginName]
```

However know that **CONTROL SERVER** gives you many rights on the instance such as the right to initiate a shut down.

Comment: Yes,I gave control server permission and it shows the same error.Looks like it need only sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

These non-sysadmin logins include windows or sql login?
How about granting read access to that schema (CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [schema].[TestTable]) to your login.

Comment: granted db_datareader to the user then also granted DBO but in both case it gave same error.Additionally granted create table,alter any schema,alter any external data source,alter any external file format.